# How to manage data for a kubernetes_config_map without conflicts

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes, terraform-aws-modules

Had an issue recently using the `terraform-aws-eks` module where we wanted to create the `aws-auth` config map and set the `mapRoles` and `mapAccounts` fields in the module but manage the `mapUsers` elsewhere.

`kubernetes_config_map_v1_data` seemed tailor made for this but we kept running into conflict issues where the fields created by `kubernetes_config_map_v1_data` kept wanting to get destroyed by the `kubernetes_config_map` resource.

We found a solution and put the answer below to anybody else having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

terraform-aws-eks module version `17`

within the terraform module `aws-auth.tf`:

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth" {
  count = var.create_eks && var.manage_aws_auth ? 1 : 0

  metadata {
    name      = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
    labels = merge(
      {
        "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by" = "Terraform"
        # / are replaced by . because label validator fails in this lib
        # https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/1bdd76d09076d4dc0362456e59c8f551f5f24a72/pkg/util/validation/validation.go#L166
        "terraform.io/module" = "terraform-aws-modules.eks.aws"
      },
      var.aws_auth_additional_labels
    )
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      data,
    ]
  }

  depends_on = [data.http.wait_for_cluster[0]]
}

resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth" {
  count = var.create_eks && var.manage_aws_auth ? 1 : 0

  metadata {
    name      = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  data = {
    mapRoles = yamlencode(
      distinct(concat(
        local.configmap_roles,
        var.map_roles,
      ))
    )
    mapAccounts = yamlencode(var.map_accounts)
  }

  field_manager = "aws-eks-module"

  depends_on = [data.http.wait_for_cluster[0], kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth[0]]
}
```

From another repo:

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth_example" {
  metadata {
    name      = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  data = {
    mapUsers = yamlencode(var.users)
  }

  field_manager = "example"
}
```